# Sed is taking the file name instead of empty value

Tags: bash, quoting

I have a replace function like

```
function replace()
{
sed -i "s#$1#$2#g" $3
}
```

I am calling the function with these parameters

```
replace MY_IP $MY_IP /usr/xxx.sh
```

where $MY_IP is a empty value
so sed is giving as `sed -i s#MY_IP#/usr/xxx.sh#g`

sed no input files

It is not taking the empty value. How to solve this?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cp_.24file_.24target

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting $MY_IP.

```
replace MY_IP "$MY_IP" /usr/xxx.sh
```

Without the quotes, `bash` will just skip that argument.

Comment: Thank u so much :)

Comment: @Heisenberg Additionally, `$3` in `replace` should be quoted.